# No me funciona los permalinks de wordpress

Tags: wordpress

He estado buscando y no encuentro como me funcione los permalinks en wordpress. Solo me sale la opcion la vista por defecto. Ya fui a las opciones y las cambie pero todas las demas me da un error.
Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

No tenia habilitado el modulo rewrite. Aqui les dejo la solución:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```